# Dynamically extendable class

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, design-patterns, architecture

I'd like to hear some suggestions and opinions about the following:

Let's say you have some entities: NewsPiece, BlogPost, Article

In general the are quite similar to each other, so I've made a generic class

```
public abstract class InformationItem<TParent, TChild, TLike>
    where TParent : InformationItem<TParent, TChild, TLike>
    where TChild : InformationItemChild<TParent, TChild, TLike>
    where TLike : InformationItemLike<TParent, TChild, TLike>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected ICollection<TChild> childItems;

    public virtual ICollection<TChild> ChildItems
    {
        get { return childItems ?? (childItems = new List<TChild>()); }
        protected set { childItems = value; }
    }

    //and so on...
}
```

Similar definitions are on the Child and Like classes, so i was able to define BaseInformationService and use it as basic implementation for all operations with my information items (Create, edit, post comment, get recent, etc...).

But recently I've faced a problem - such implementation enforces the structure of the derived classes and makes classes that don't need comments (for example) to have unnecessary functionality. So I've decided to make this implementation a little bit more flexible - i want to have something like InformationItemServiceBuilder that will have methods such as .WithComments or .WithLikes which will be able to construct information item service with needed functionality only.

Which approach or design pattern would you suggest? Should i try decorator, or something else will fit better? Thank you in advance for you replies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the a `dynamic` object?  The DLR allows you to create properties and methods dynamically.  There are a few open source projects that provide custom implementations which would let you easily add properties and methods dynamically, as well as dynamically implement known interfaces.  The dynamic interface implementations rely on dynamic proxies and you can mix-in interfaces (e.g. `ISupportComments`) to add your partitioned functionality.

I would recommend taking a look at the following two projects:

1. [Clay](http://clay.codeplex.com/)

   - http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/16/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-1-why-we-need-it.aspx
   - http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/18/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-2.aspx
2. [Impromptu Interface](https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/)

In addition, Jeremy Miller has a good article on implementing persistent extension properties that seem to be along the lines of what you are trying to build.  It might give you some ideas to give it a read at: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2010/02/16/our-extension-properties-story/

Comment: So, I've tried to use this, but this is not what i need - it only allows dynamic object to be applicable as interface implementor, but that's not the point. Any other ideas?

Comment: @HardLuck - I believe that you are mistaken about the limitations of these libraries.  The articles on Clay show how you can build deep object graphs dynamically (supporting Comments, etc.).  however, in general, I think that you're solution is a bit over-engineered, and that you would be better off creating concrete classes that derive from a minimal non-generic base class.  Then, you can handle the variation in the subtypes implicitly via your ORM configuration ... but that's just how I would handle it.

Comment: @HardLuck - It's also possible that I misunderstood your objection to the resources I referenced.  if you think this is the case, then you can post the code you are using and what exactly is "not working" for your purpose.  this should probably be in another question, but if you do decide to do this I will make sure to look at it.